# Swift: Delegate of UITextField in UITableViewCell does not work

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to set the delegate of my `titleTF` to my `UITableViewCell` or my `UITableView`. This is how I set up the textField inside my `UITableViewCell` class.

```
class AddAppointmentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
var view = UIView()
var titleTF = UITextField()

func addTitle() -> UIView {
    view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height:
        NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Title", attributes: [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24),
                                                               .foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray]).size().height+30))

    titleTF.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    titleTF.textAlignment = .left
    titleTF.delegate = self
    titleTF.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Title", attributes: [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24),
                                                                                    .foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])
    titleTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    view.addSubview(titleTF)
    titleTF.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    titleTF.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    titleTF.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    titleTF.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -15)
    return view
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("textFieldDidEndEditing")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    addSubview(view)
}
}
```

This is inside my `UITableView` class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rows.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return rows[indexPath.row].frame.height
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddAppointmentTableViewCell
    cell.view = rows[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And `rows` is equals `[cell.addTitle(), cell.addNote()]`

I don't understand why the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method inside my `UITableViewCell` isn't called.

Comment: Show your `AddAppointmentTableViewCell `

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?

Comment: Your tableview cell and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method

Comment: is this everything you need?

Comment: "titleTF.delegate = self"  Nobody even knows where and how titleTF is defined.

Comment: override func awakeFromNib() {
 super.awakeFromNib()
    titleTF.delegate = self
}

Comment: can you please explain why this does work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call the delegate inside the awakeFromNib (had the same problem):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textField.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line

{

textField.delegate = self

}